# What would a diagram of the lattice structure of CuSO4 look like?

Tags: crystal-structure

Just as $\ce{NaCl}$ would look like this:
[image: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/@api/deki/files/43140/IMG00003.GIF?revision=1]

What would a diagram of $\ce{CuSO4}$ look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the WebElements.com page on [copper sulphate](http://www.webelements.com/compounds/copper/copper_sulphate.html), the metal lattice structure looks like:

[image]

The yellow pyramids are cooper and the other structures are sulphates.

An alternate view comes from the Wikipedia page of [copper (II) sulphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_sulfate):

[image]

The pink spheres represent copper, yellow are sulphur and red are oxygen.

Below is a 2D representation of copper sulphate, from the [Royal Society of Chemistry](http://www.rsc.org/learn-chemistry/wiki/Substance:Copper(II)_sulfate)

[image]

A similar question with some more insight is found in [How do copper sulphate and the like change crystal structure on adding water of hydration?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/544/how-do-copper-sulphate-and-the-like-change-crystal-structure-on-adding-water-of)